# Stuck in loop? App doesnt crash but nothing displays or work either

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist

Im having an method that are supposed to return an arraylist of "item" (contains three strings, name,imageurl,audiourl).

In the filesystem i have matching names of files (except extension jpg,png,mp3) in same folder.

Im trying to search through that folder and gather all the files that have matching either jpg/png to mp3. and putting this in the arraylist.

I though it with this code:

```
   public ArrayList<PictureItem> getArrayOfPictureItemFromFolder(String directoryPath) {
    ArrayList<PictureItem> arrayOfPictureItems = new ArrayList<PictureItem>();
    PictureItem pi;
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File[] imageListing = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
            }
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    File[] audioListing = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
        }
    });

    if (imageListing != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageListing.length; i++) {
            String imagePath = imageListing[i].toString();
            String imagetitle = imageListing[i].getName();
            int removeImageExtension = imagetitle.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (removeImageExtension > 0) {
                imagetitle = imagetitle.substring(0, removeImageExtension);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < audioListing.length; i++) {
                String audioPath = audioListing[j].toString();
                String audioTitle = audioListing[j].getName();
                int removeAudioExtension = audioTitle.lastIndexOf(".");
                audioTitle = audioTitle.substring(0, removeAudioExtension);
                if (imagetitle.equals(audioTitle)) {
                    pi = new PictureItem(imagePath, imagetitle);
                    pi.setSoundPath(audioPath);
                    arrayOfPictureItems.add(pi);
                }
            }
        }


    } else {
        return null;
    }


    return arrayOfPictureItems;

}
```

But for some reason when i launch the code the it only goes to black screen and im unable to "go back" to main menu with back button.

Logcat just repeats this constantly(let it run for quite some time).

```
11-27 01:59:29.778    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC   
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
11-27 01:59:29.939    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC   
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-27 01:59:30.108    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC 
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
11-27 01:59:30.278    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC 
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-27 01:59:30.439    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC 
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
11-27 01:59:30.611    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC 
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-27 01:59:30.778    7424-7424/picturedtalk.com.picturedtalk D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC 
freed 3072K (98250), 43% free 4233K/7424K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
```

I know the rest of the app works when i just had scanned the directory and added everything to an arraylist without sorting names. Ive tried to set breakpoints and run in debug mode but it refuses to stop anywhere in that code, including the pre launch code. if i // everything except return arrayOfPictureItems the app return button works again and so does the breakpoint...

Comment: Dough! i just saw when looking over code that i have i++ on second for loop which should be j... That fixed the "lock" and i now display pictures with sound. BUT they are not matching correctly. If i press an image of a cat it plays audio = dog...

Comment: Any suggestion whats wrong with my sorting/matching function? im at a loss atm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd for loop increments `i` instead of `j` - so `j` never changes.